# Generic function parameter with unknown args

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a reason that specifying a generic parameter as a function with `...args: unknown[]` doesn't play nicely?

```js
// Using TS 4.2.3
const fn = (foo: boolean) => 'hello'

// Ideally, one generic function arg
type Data1<M extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown> = {
  fn: M
}
const data1: Data1<typeof fn> = {
                   ^^^^^^^^^
  fn,
}
```

```
Type '(foo: boolean) => string' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: unknown[]) => unknown'.
  Types of parameters 'foo' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

This [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAKOIQC4YCNMA2ApgIZgCUyAfDAOQAWRBBItAUGwPScwCSAJqWYBPADQxwRGAHMiYIgCcAlsHgBXMMChLwMEgulsowgA5SAIiSgkAjAB4AsjCIAPKHP4Q0AOl-7pEDgaANZgIADuYADaALqUSDQhYZE0KADebDDwYDgObAC+bKCQsPxWtjiW1vbGZiBw2akwGVkIogUc3Hyw4SAKwV7hjIjCIGowEEQm+lZSUIww0wokALZeY7BKYFAgMFC94rhqsGGwJgpEUMYwW3uKaxINAIIACrxGphblAEx2TwZeVzuMCeGBJCKIWLiABKlzUCkQQI8XnBKWQzUy2RwqF83n8gRg-wC8RosKg8LAHWK0BgZWs30qPzsLxmK0uiggdlqRHqjRhcIRABVPlzPryEFQmi1su1CkA) example also demonstrates splitting the function into two generic parameters, which works but isn't nice from an API point of view. I'm hoping to better understand why one works, but the other doesn't.

Comment: `M extends Function`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that would work. I guess its equivalent to `M extends (...args: any[]) => any`. Still interested as to why it doesn't like `...args: unknown[]` though .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens due to [variance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance).

```typescript
declare function fn(foo: boolean): string

type Data1<M extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown> = {
  fn: M
}

const data1: Data1<typeof fn> = {
                      ^
// Type '(foo: boolean) => string' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: unknown[]) => unknown'.
//  Types of parameters 'foo' and 'args' are incompatible.
//    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  fn,
}
```

Your data type `Data1` accepting a function type is covariant in that functions's result type and contravariant in functions's argument type. Imagine it (`Data1`) as a function (what it really is on type-level) accepting an argument `(foo: boolean) => string`. This function has to check whether this argument is 'assignable' to parameter's type `(...args: unknown[]) => unknown`. To check this checker must ensure two things:

- function's return type `string` must be assignable to `unknown`. That is totally possible. All types are assignable to `unknown`.
- parameter's argument type `unknown[]` must be assignable to function's argument type [`boolean`]. That's where the checker raises the error. Because `unknown` is assignable only to `unknown` and `any`.

Why does it have to happen in the opposite direction when it comes to the arguments? Because the function passed as an argument is a consumer of data. It **must** handle a wider range of types than the function expected as a parameter. Simple example:

```typescript
function lowerCase(s: string): string {
  return s.toLowerCase()
}

function callCb(cb: (sn: string | number) => string | number): number {
  const stringOrNumber = cb(Math.random() ? 'string' : 10)

  return typeof stringOrNumber === 'string' 
    ? stringOrNumber.length 
    : stringOrNumber  ​
} 

callCb(lowerCase)
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/N7baDw)  with `strictFunctionTypes` turned off to illustrate unsoundness.

While `cb` can return any subset of `callCb`'s expected parameter return type (string, number, string | number) `cb` must be able to handle **every** type `callCb` can provide to it.

---

```typescript
type Data2<Args extends unknown [], Return extends unknown> = {
 ​fn: (...args: Args) => Return
}

const data2: Data2<Parameters<typeof fn>, ReturnType<typeof fn>> = {
 ​fn,
}
```

As for your `Data2` type. You're providing it with exact `fn`'s argument and result types both in covariant/positive position. First it checks whether the provided types are satisfying constraints:

​* first type argument `[boolean]` is assignable to `unknown[]`
​* second type argument `string` is assignable to `unknown`

Then it checks whether the object you're passing on the right hand side of the assignment with type `{ fn: (foo: boolean) => string }` is assignable to `Data2`'s result type `{ fn: (...[boolean]) => string }`. That it clearly is.

---

You can turn off this behavior by disabling [`strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) option in `tsconfig.json`. Then typescript treats function arguments as bivariant. Though I'd strongly advise against that.
​